# Pafy audio not video streams in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an audio streamer that grabs the url of a youtube video and plays it, but I want it to be only audio as I am using it as an audio player, also a raspberry pi zero cannot handle full 1080p video.
The code I have so far that plays video:

```
import pafy
import vlc
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3jege0p0dQ"
video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

I'm not completly sure pafy has an audio stream function, so if it doesnt and there is another solution apart from Pafy please tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the docs on pafy and realized all I had to do is change `best = video.getbest()` to 
**`best = video.getbestaudio()`**